# FFMPEG DTS Max Bitrate

Tags: ffmpeg, powershell, bitrate

Recently having problems with the DTS part of FFMPEG.
When defining a bitrate higher than 1536kb/s, the end result reverts to 640kb/s.
Using 1536kb/s or lower seems to have no problems.
Is this normal behavior or am I doing something wrong.

This is using Powershell with the following command.

& "$LocationFfmpeg" -i $VideoInput -strict -2 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:a:1 -map 0:a:1 -c:v copy -c:a:0 copy -c:a:1 dts -b:a 1920k -c:a:2 ac3 -disposition:a:0 default -disposition:a:1 none -disposition:a:2 none $VideoOutput -loglevel error -stats

$LocationFfmpeg -> where FFMPEG is stored

$VideoInput -> location of input file

$VideoOutput -> location of output file

Thanks for any info about this.